# Why the 'each' loop does not run when the array is empty

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a script assertion that should just spot check each item in the response and check that each item is the correct data type.
I noticed that when the response is empty the each loop does not seem to run, therefore the assertion passes where it should not.

Rule ID is a field in the response, but when the request criteria does not match any deal, it will return an empty array.

Is this the correct behaviour for an each loop? If so what would be the best loop to use?

Code below and Thanks in advance

added this Groovy snippet

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def response = context.expand( '${POST/instant-deal/get-applicable-request#Response}' ).toString()
def jsonRes = slurper.parseText(response)

RuleId = jsonRes.RuleId
RuleId.each { RuleID ->
    log.error "Rule IDs: " + RuleID
    assert RuleID != null
    assert RuleID instanceof Integer    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a loop around an empty list will exit immediately.

You are doing something like:

```
def expected = [1,2,3]
def actual = myMethod() // returns a list of int
actual.each { x ->
   assert expected.contains(x)
}
```

As you've noted, this passes for `actual == []`, or `[1]` or `[1,3]` or `[3,2,1]` -- what it's saying is, "I don't need anything to be in `actual`, but anything that *is* in there, must be a member of `expected`.

If instead you want to ensure that every member of `expected` is also in `actual`, you should loop around `expected` instead:

```
expected.each { x ->
   assert actual.contains(x)
}
```

This checks that every member of `expected` is present in `actual`, but doesn't mind if `actual` contains more members. So it would pass for `[1,2,3]`, `[3,2,1]` but also for `[1,2,3,3]` or `[1,2,3,4]` - That may be what you need.

If you want to check that the lists are exactly the same, just use `actual == expected` (in Groovy... in Java you'd need to use `.equals()`)

What precisely you should do, depends on exactly what you are trying to assert. At the moment, what you describe: "spot check each item in the response and check that each item is the correct data type."  *should* pass for an empty list, because every item in the list (i.e. none) has the correct type.

Comment: I am trying to assert that the json property RuleID is present in the response and that all the IDs are an instance of int . Also why would it pass if that property does not exist in the json response? Thanks

Comment: Since RuleId is a list (in JSON: `"RuleId" : [ 3 ]`, my guess is that you have one more requirement: that the list is not empty. If that's right, then have one more assert, outside the loop -- `assert RuleId != []`

Comment: BTW in Java and Groovy -- and usually in JSON -- the convention is for variables to start with a lower case letter. `ruleId` not `RuleId`. `RuleId` looks like a class name.

Comment: "Why would it pass if that property does not exist in the Java response" -- that depends on JSON deserializer used, and its configuration. That will affect whether it translates an absent value that's expected to be a list into `null` or `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not valid to have an empty RuleId then add:

```
...
RuleId = jsonRes.RuleId
assert RuleId
...
```